# Java tictactoe problems with minmax algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, minmax

i want to implement the MinMax algorithm for tictactoe. I have two methods 
min() and max() and a evaluation method, but it doesn't works. For example when i call

```
max(9);
Field[bestCol][bestRow]='O';
min(8);
Field[bestCol][bestRow]='X';
```

in the main function the result is

```
OX-                                  
---
---
```

But the best Move for Player 'X' is to put the 'X' in the middle.

Here is my Code without the evaluation Method:

```
static char[][] Field = { { '-', '-', '-' },
                          { '-', '-', '-' },
                          { '-', '-', '-' } };

static char Player = 'O';
static char Computer = 'X';

static int Depth =9; // searchdepth
static int bestRow=0, bestCol=0; // best Move

public static int max(int depth) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        return evaluateMove();
    }

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (Field[i][j] == '-') {
                Field[i][j] = Computer;

                int value = min(depth - 1);
                Field[i][j] ='-';

                if (value > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = value;
                    if (depth == Depth) {
                        bestCol=i;
                        bestRow=j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

public static int min(int depth) {
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    if (depth == 0) {
        return evaluateMove();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (Field[i][j] == '-') {
                Field[i][j] = Player;
                int value = max(depth - 1);
                Field[i][j] = '-';

                if (value < minValue) {
                    minValue = value;
                    bestCol=i;
                    bestRow=j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

Best Regards

EDIT:

Thanks for your answer. To the first point i have forgotten to change the '*' to '-' Here is my Evaluation Method:

```
public static int evaluateMove() {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        int countX=0; int countY=0;
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            if(Feld[i][j]==Computer) countX++;
            if(Feld[i][j]==Player) countY++;
        }
        if(countX==3) return 10;
        if(countY==3) return -10;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) { // Spalten
        int countX=0; int countY=0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if(Feld[i][j]==Computer) countX++;
            if(Feld[i][j]==Player) countY++;
            if(countX==3) return 10;
            if(countY==3) return -10;
        }
    }
    return 0; // Unentschieden
}
```

Comment: How does evaluateMove() do it's job? What is eingestellteTiefe? Shouldn't it be Depth?

Comment: It returns 10 if the Computer wins, 0 if it's a draw and -10 if the player wins

Comment: And eingestellteTiefe? == Depth?

Comment: sorry, i have translate it from German, "eingestelleteTiefe" means Depth

Comment: Could you post the evaluateMove method? I don't want to write it from scratch. And it could also be the source of the problem.

Comment: I have post the evaluateMove function

Comment: See my edited answer. No time at the moment to test the result. Later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that struck me:

1. you are initializing the empty squares of the playing field with '-', but in the min/max-functions you assume that '*' is an empty square
2. in the min-function, as opposed to the max-function you set the best move at every level instead of the top level, so the deeper levels will overwrite the best result from the top level (so I think you should also check for depth==Depth)
3. I don't know what you do in main, but should also decrement "Depth" after each move, because this defines the top level (and thus the level where the best move should be assigned), and according to your question you decrement the "depth" argument during each call
4. I guess you know that you will only get the optimal result if you recurse until the end of the game (which is another argument for decrementing depth and Depth after every move)
5. **You are not checking the diagonals in your evaluateMove function**
6. In your second double loop in evaluateMove you check the condition for countX, countY inside the innermost loop (works, but it is irritating that it's different to first double loop => not so good for finding errors)

**Edit:** and finally (drum roll...):

7. In the first move you **maximize** the gain (for a Computer move ('X')) but you actually perform a Player move ('O'). For the second move vice versa. However, you have to **minimize** the gain in the first move (which means player wins) and maximize in the second move.

**That is, what you actually do:**

```
    public static void ComputeAndExecuteBestMove()
    {
        // since Player begins, we minimize the gain value for the first move
        if ((MaxDepth-Depth) % 2 == 0) 
        {
            max(Depth);
            Field[bestCol,bestRow] = Player;
        }
        else 
        {
            min(Depth);
            Field[bestCol,bestRow] = Computer;
        }

        // next move
        Depth--;
    }
```

**but what you should do:**

```
    public static void ComputeAndExecuteBestMove()
    {
        // since Player begins, we minimize the gain value for the first move
        if ((MaxDepth-Depth) % 2 == 0) 
        {
            min(Depth);
            Field[bestCol,bestRow] = Player;
        }
        else 
        {
            max(Depth);
            Field[bestCol,bestRow] = Computer;
        }

        // next move
        Depth--;
    }
```

Comment: Now i check the diagonals too. I have corrected your 2. point, but when i now call in main() max(9);
  
  Field[bestCol][bestRow]='X';    
  Depth--;  
  min(8);    
  Field[bestCol][bestRow]='O';
  Depth--; it's the same as before.

Comment: @Javabeginner: have you corrected the min function already? (bullet #2)

Comment: Yes, i have add            if (depth == Depth) {
          bestCol=i;
       bestRow=j;                      
      } in the min() function

Comment: sorry but i don't understand that, I called the method differently than you wrote. And is MaxDepth=9?

Comment: Yes MaxDepth=9. The question is, why do you call it differenly? (see bullet #3). When I do all this, the second move is X in the center.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot now it works.I my Opinion It's easier to understand if ((Depth) % 2 == 1)   instead of if ((MaxDepth-Depth) % 2 == 0).